# How to log entity content from Jersey if ConstraintValidationException is thrown?

Tags: bean-validation, jersey-2.0

I have an endpoint with one operation: doSomething. This operation accepts "application/json" content type that is mapped to an instance of "DoSomethingRequest" class.

Class "DoSomethingRequest" uses standard Validation to forbid some bad combination of parameters and it also works perfectly well.

Now the tough part. Since it is the Validation framework that does this dirty job for me, how do I log contents of such bad request - when none of my endpoint code gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the log level works, but you would by side effect log a lot of irrelevant things. The log level used seems to be `FINER`. See also https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/bean-validation/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/validation/internal/ValidationExceptionMapper.java

You also would have not control how it would be logged. IMO a better approach would be  to write your on custom `ExceptionMapper` for `ConstraintViolationException`. See also http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/28/handling-jax-rs-and-bean-validation-errors-with-mvc/#bv-errors

Comment: Yeah, using FINER mode in production is a bit insane. We already have proper exception mappers, but I wanted to just dump entire original JSON that is sent to my endpoint - seems it is not doable.

Instead, I have increased amount of information logged from ConstraintViolationException and ConstraintViolation. Now I log not only ConstraintViolation.getMessage() but also ConstraintViolation.getInvalidObject() as well. It should do the trick :)